# Render XML data with ReactLayout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The XML data in `PhoneCallResponse` does not appear in the generated HMTL.
Probably because React uses XML for its components.

Is there a special way to handle this?

```
PhoneCallResponse = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <Response>
                <Say voice="alice">
                    Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice U R L to change this message.
                </Say>
                <Pause length="1"/>
                <Say voice="alice">
                    Let us know if we can help you in any way during your development.
                </Say>
            </Response>
        );
    }
});


FlowRouter.route('/twilio/', {
    action: function() {    
        ReactLayout.render(Layout, {
            content: <PhoneCallResponse />
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React reasons with JSX (it's not XML!) this way: Capital letter at the start of the tag indicates a React component. Lowercase tags are rendered straight out as DOM elements without further computation. At the end of the day, React renders HTML views, not XML.

Your code will cause a reference error, as neither Response, Say or Pause are defined components. The reason is the way JSX is transpiled before React ever does anything: JSX tags with a capital letter are treated as components. So `<Response></Response>` will be converted to `React.createElement(Response, {}, null)`, and if `Response` isn't a valid React component within the scope, the javascript engine will complain, and everything crashes. Lowercase tags however are treated as strings, and React will simply render an HTML tag `<response></response>`

If you insist on mixing XML in with your HTML, or your goal is to render an XML document, then use lowercase tags or [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) which is the React way of injecting strings in the DOM. Keep in mind however that HTML5 is not XML in the way that XHTML was, and XHTML is more or less dead. Standard compliant custom tags these days follow the pattern `<x-custom-tag>`, `<x-another-custom-tag>` and so forth, just to make sure you avoid any name collision that might be caused by new tags in a future HTML standard.

On a side note: React plays well with HTML5 custom elements and shadow DOM. Sadly, this part of the HTML standard is very "work in progress", and apparently miles away from being ready to use, but as of Chrome version 49 this example should demonstrate the general idea: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/je8pmazk/.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Can you please add a working example with dangerouslySetInnerHTML as well as my example code?

Comment: @BAR I think the documentation is a better resource than I am. But something like this: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<Response>.... etc ...</Response> '}}></div>`. Please read the documentation anyway, because you should really try to avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if you don't know what it is and how it works.

Comment: I ask because it did not work.  And lowercase won't work here because the app that reads the XML expects capitalized tags.

Comment: It works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/upLeuxky/. I render both into the DOM and as a string just to illustrate the difference. Upon inspection in Chrome etc, all tags are lowercase, but that's just because HTML is case insensitive, and Chrome builds the DOM with lowercase tags behind the scenes. The rendered string, that you would use on the server, remains with capitalized tags.